# Can't pass an array and a string into controller with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I hope someone can help me with this issue that I have.

I'm trying to pass an array into controller with JavaScript like this:

```
$('#send') .lick(function () {
    var items = {};
    var grid = $('#grid') .ata('kendoGrid');
    var selectedElements = grid .elect();

    for (var j = 0; j < selectedElements .ength; j++) {
        var item = grid .ataItem(selectedElements[j]);
        items['grid[' + j + '] .arecidoCodigo'] = item .arecidoCodigo;

    }

    $ .jax({
        type: "POST",
        data: items,
        url: '@Url .ction("Index", "Busqueda")',
        success: function (result) {
            console .og(result);
        }
    })
})
```

This works fine.

But when I tried to pass another value, in this case a string data, the array is sending null into the controller but the string value is not null.

This is my code when I tried to send another value, in this case the array and the string data:

```
$('#send') .lick(function () {
    var items = {};
    var grid = $('#grid') .ata('kendoGrid');
    var selectedElements = grid .elect();
    var enviarDest = $('#destinatario') .al();

    for (var j = 0; j < selectedElements .ength; j++) {
        var item = grid .ataItem(selectedElements[j]);
        items['grid[' + j + '] .arecidoCodigo'] = item .arecidoCodigo;

    }
    var postData = { marcas: items, destinatario: enviarDest };
    $ .jax({
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        url: '@Url .ction("Index", "Busqueda")',
        success: function (result) {
            console .og(result);
        }
    })
})
```

And this is the code of my controller:

```c#
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(List<MarcaParecido> marcas, string destinatario)
{
 ..
}
```

Here is when I receive the list `marcas` null and the string `destinatario` is not null, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What is the `MarcaParecido` model and which property of it are you trying to bind to?

Comment: You have several syntax errors in your code. It appears as though some letters just aren't coming in. For instance, it's `$.ajax` not `$ .jax`. Also, the problem is likely that you're using an object for `items`/`marcas`, not an array, to represent a `List<T>`, which probably won't work. You'd want a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` if you want an an object.

Comment: The thing is that when i pass only the array into the controller it work, but when i tried to pass another value is sending null. I tried with this too MarcaParecido[] marcas and is the same thing. Only works when i pass only the array. And i need to pass the other value too.

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify(postData)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JsonResult instead of async in your controller:

```
public JsonResult Index(List<MarcaParecido> marcas, string destinatario) 
{ .. }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but that it throws me an error syntax.

Comment: i´m sorry but it still send me null the array but the string parameter isn´t null. I don´t know what else can i do :(

Comment: For kendo grids there is

Comment: It's explain completely in that link how you can do that, it's important to use DataSourceRequest type, otherwise the controller doesn't recognize the passed data properly, you need to change your method to this:  public JsonResult Index([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request) , if you can try that that's more recommended, I remember I had very similar issue, and for no reason the controller couldn't recognise my passed data, but it's fine after using the pattern described in the link.

Comment: i understand, but the thing is that i want to send other values into a controller when i clik on the send button.

Comment: This is the thing that i want to do. I have a grid and when i click on the row of a grid i get the id of that row, and that is what i put into the array, and when i click send i want to pass that array in my controller, and i have other value that is an string email. Bu when i try to send both the array is null but the string isn't.